# Package Level Composer Not Triggered in Lumen Package Development

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm trying to create a package to publish in packagist, for this I am using the package level composer.json to install the dependencies.

my package level composer.json is as follow

```
{
    "name": "my-company/my-package",
    "description": "Package Desciption",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "email": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^4.1"
    }
}
```

I declare this on my main root autoload in composer.json as follow:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "MyCompany\\MyPackage\\": "packages/my-company/my-package/"
        }
    },
```

when I run the composer install in the root `composer.json` the child composer.json is not triggered.

Comment: Have you published to packagist already?

Comment: Also can you include the `require` array block of your `composer.json`

Comment: no i am not packed yet

Comment: It wont be available for your local project unless you `symlink` the package, upload to a git repository and link to it, or add to packagist. To confirm what you have done add the `require` part of your `composer.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I solve this by adding repository block and define the path in the root composer.json and also adding the newly create package name into the require-dev

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "packages/my-company/my-package"
    }
  ],
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "my-company/my-package": "1.0.*"
  },
```